# How to update data in my android application?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app.How can i update the data in my app using web server? 
Initially,i will provide the data in my application itself.But when my data becomes outdated,how will i update that data in the application itself?Is there any way to do this using internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite general question, so there are plenty of ways to update the application data.

I assume that you have a web service and it provides the necessary content of your application.For example, If the web service sends you the content with json format then you need to parse and save the data to use later when you don't have internet connection.This is just an example to make you aware about one of the simple way.

And If you are asking about the data you put in your application when you create the application, let's say the data in assets folder, you cannot over write the data there. If you want to use the updated the data from internet, then you need to save it somehow. You can keep the file sent from server directly or you can parse the data and create database to use it.

Comment: Hi.. This answer helps.. But the scenario is my data is somewhat which is rarely changed. So will it be good to use a web service? Initially I want to embed database in my app. But if it needs to be changed then what should i do? Is there any way to change it in app? I do not want my users to have access to web every-time they open my app.

Comment: Ok then, first of all, if you want your application is updateable then you have to use a kind of web service, this is must. Otherwise I don't see any other way to update the data in the application. If it is like the content changes once in a year or something, then you can just update your application in the market, no thing else.

Comment: So, If we deal that you will use a web service and if your data rarely changes and if you don't want to users connects internet checks whether a new data is available or not, then there is only one way. It's "Google cloud messaging". In the case you update something in the web service, you can send a message to the users with GCM, which says "my application is updated". then you make them to update their data when they got the message.

Comment: I will tell you another way which I use in my applications, I mostly put a update date to my web service and whenever user connects internet and opens the application, application checks the update date and compares with the old one, if the data is updated then I get the rest of the data from service. In this way , you don't use that much band width.

Comment: Hmm.. Updating my application sounds best for my scenario. So that I don't need to worry about web services or GCM. But when my application is updated in market then how to inform my users about the update?

Comment: Dont't worry, Google informs them when there is an update for any of the applications installed in their android device.

Answer (score 0):

To get notification froms server that there is update avaible use push notification: [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) (GCM).

Then you have to just fetch data for exaple ussing http protocol. Your question is to general to give better answer.